# How do I get an indeterminate number of command line arguments in a bash script?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I am writing a `bash` script to be run on macOS Sonoma

```
$bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin23)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

My script is to read a source file line by line, apply some logic to each line, and write it into one of the target files.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <source file> <target 1> <target 2> ... <target n>"
    exit 1
elif [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <source file> <target 1> <target 2> ... <target n>"
    exit 1
fi

numFiles=$(($# - 1))
echo "${numFiles} target files"

sourceFile="$1"
echo "Source file: ${sourceFile}"

targetFiles=(${@: 2})
echo "Target files: ${targetFiles}"
```

I would expect `targetFiles` to be an array of the target files.

However, when I run this as

```
splitFile.sh source.txt t1.txt t2.txt t3.txt
```

I only get

```
3 target files
Source file: source.txt
Target files: t1.txt
```

I would expect the last line to be

```
Target files: t1.txt t2.txt t3.txt
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Shellcheck identifies what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`targetFiles` is an array. To print the array, you need to use array notation

```
echo "Target files: ${targetFiles[*]}"
```

will give you all values.

Comment: Avoid using `*` as array key, better use `@`.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005

Comment: `*` is correct when the goal is to create a single word containing the contents of the array. Compare `printf '%s\n' "Files: ${targetFiles[*]}"` with `printf '%\n' "Files: ${targetFiles[@]}"`.

Comment: @chepner: most of the time, the default should be to use `@` if you don't explicitly need `*`

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
targetFiles=($@)
echo "Target files: ${targetFiles[@]:1}"
```

The variable:

```
${targetFiles}
```

is wrong. For an array, **always** use `${array[<indice(s)>]}`

---

Always pass your scripts to https://shellcheck.net before asking help here.

You could discover:

```
echo "Target files: ${targetFiles}"
                    ^------------^ SC2128 (warning): Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element.
```

Comment: *Always* quote `$@`; unquoted, it is no different than `$*`.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need for an array. You can (and arguably should, given how old `bash` 3.2 is) write a POSIX-compliant script that doesn't require any `bash` extensions here.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <source file> <target 1> <target 2> ... <target n>"
    exit 1
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <source file> <target 1> <target 2> ... <target n>"
    exit 1
fi


sourceFile="$1"
echo "Source file: ${sourceFile}"

shift

numFiles=$(($#))
echo "${numFiles} target files"


echo "Target files: $*"

for target in "$@"; do
   ...
done
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I would do, too.  But there seems no particular need for `$(($#))` instead of just `$#`, and quite possibly no need for a separate `numFiles` variable at all.  And although it's not the OP's focus, the argument count checks could also be combined into one, with condition `[ $# -lt 2 ]`.

Comment: Yeah, I remembered to remove the `- 1`, but then neglected to remove the now-unnecessary arithmetic expression.